# how to enable cursor location reporting in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

in pycharm if I have a dictionary like

[image]

and put my cursor on the number 2, as you can see in the toolbar it is showing me that the cursor is at the location:

**Document 1/1 > a > b > item 2/2 > item 3/3 > item 2/2 > 2**

or if my cursor clicks inside a method of a class the same can be seen
[image]

How can I have the same in vscode? what should I add to the settings.json so that I can achieve the same?

Comment: why do you think VSC has all the features of all the other editors, it all depends on the stuff implemented by the Language Server and if it uses an AST, you can have a look at the OUTLINE View maybe it changes the selection based on the cursor position

Comment: VSCode allows for the installation of extension packs. Look through those to see if one of them has implemented this for you. I have a number of them installed, and I can see where the cursor is as you are looking for, but I couldn't tell you which one actually did that... Install some of the extensions.